# Non derivative functions

Tags: derivatives

What is an example of a function that is not a derivative of another function? For example $2x$ is the derivative of $x^2$ I was thinking of some examples such that a function say $f$, there exist no $g'$ such that $f=g'$.

Comment: You need something that doesn't have the intermediate value property, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis), so it's going to look pretty nasty.

Comment: Would $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \neq 0 \\ 1, & x = 0\end{cases}$$ work?

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 1,\\
1 & x \geq 1\end{cases}
$$
This does not have the intermediate value property. All derivatives have it.